# How to make a window inside a blurred window in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frontend

This means when a **blur** is created **on top** of **the main content** of the program and a window is created above it with completely different content, inside the program.
Like here:

[image: Example of this concept #1]
[image: Example of this concept #2]

I tried to create **another window inside** by writing it directly in xaml, as shown below, and technically it works, but I'm sure there is a much simpler way, and more universal, so that I don't have to write these * every time *pop-ups** over and over again, like the example below. I searched for a long time but never found anything useful

> An example of markup that can be simplified and optimized for different pages:

```
<!--MainContent1.xaml-->
<Grid x:Name="Main_Content1">
    <Border x:Name="popup_1" CornerRadius="5" Visibility="Hidden" Z.Index="0">
        <Grid>
            <!--Content of popup1-->
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="popup_2" CornerRadius="5" Visibility="Hidden" Z.Index="0">
        <Grid>
            <!--Content of popup2-->
            <Button/>
            <TextBlock/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="popup_3" CornerRadius="5" Visibility="Hidden" Z.Index="0">
        <Grid>
            <!--Content of popup3-->
            <TextBlock/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>

<!--MainContent2.xaml-->
<Grid x:Name="Main_Content2">
    <Border x:Name="popup_1" CornerRadius="5" Visibility="Hidden" Z.Index="0">
        <Grid>
            <!--Content of popup1-->
            <Button/>
            <Button/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>

<!--and other files-->
```

Comment: "I'm sure there is a much simpler way, but I can't find another way anywhere." - if you are sure, then keep looking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: He who searches will always find, and if necessary he will create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this issue and came up with this template, which you can find on Github [here](https://github.com/kenuel0110/WPF-CSharp-Window-Template-with-Popup)

This is my project in which the solution to this problem is described in detail, and it does not fit here completely

> (The original question was created in 4 January 2023, but for some reason it was deleted, so I created it again and answered because I found a solution and want to show it to others, otherwise why does this site exist?)